# UIImageView loading from URL with cancellable task and safe to use in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to make a UIImageView class / extension that can load an image from a URL.

the image view should not get confused with concurrency when scrolling through a UICollectionView and the data task should be cancellable. Also downloaded images should be cached (I'm not sure if NSCache or URLCache should be used here)

I would like to utilise the latest Swift APIs if possible.

Where should I make a reference to the Task object so that I can easily cancel these requests at a later point?

I have written this code and I am wondering if anybody can spot anything wrong or anything they believe could improve the code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {
    func setImage(url: URL , contentMode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        image = nil
        Task {
            do {
                let (image, returnedURL) = try await ImageService.shared.downloadImage(url: url)
                guard url == returnedURL else {
                    setImage(url: url, contentMode: contentMode)
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = image
                    self.contentMode = contentMode
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

class ImageService {
    static let shared = ImageService()
    static var imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
    func downloadImage(url: URL) async throws -> (UIImage, URL) {
        if let image = ImageService.imageCache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            return (image, url)
        } else {
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            guard let (data, _) = try? await URLSession(configuration: .default).data(for: urlRequest) else {
                throw "Could not download image"
            }
            if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                ImageService.imageCache.setObject(image as AnyObject, forKey: url.absoluteString as AnyObject)
                return (image, url)
            } else {
                throw "Could not decode image"
            }
        }
    }
}

extension String: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? { return self }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the code and is it working as intended?

Comment: @pacmaninbw yes I think so - I'm not sure how to test URL caching, I just wanted people's opinions how I can refer to the Task()

Comment: Think in terms of Separation of Concerns, a `UIImageView` shouldn't care about HTTP requests or caching etc.